# AWS Glue Studio is not creating Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

So I've been using AWS Glue Studio to create ETL jobs. I currently set it up so that the target node was an S3 bucket, however I also want to create a table on the Data Catalog. However, once I run the ETL job it doesn't mark an error and it does correctly save the output as a Parquet file to my S3 bucket, however it does not create a table in the Data Catalog.

This is my code:

```
node hem-horarios-bpi hemhorariosbpi_node3 = glueContext.getSink(
path="s3://hem-data-datalake-staging/staging_general/staging_horarioHP/", connection_type="s3", updateBehavior="LOG", partitionKeys=[], enableUpdateCatalog=True, transformation_ctx="hemhorariosbpi_node3", ) 
hemhorariosbpi_node3.setCatalogInfo( catalogDatabase="hem-db-staging-tables", catalogTableName="hem-horarios-pbi" )
hemhorariosbpi_node3.setFormat("glueparquet") 
hemhorariosbpi_node3.writeFrame(S3bucket_node1) 
job.commit()
```

I have tried changing the role, but it won't do.

Comment: Could you provide your script? Otherwise it is really hard to debug :)

Comment: # Script generated for node hem-horarios-bpi
hemhorariosbpi_node3 = glueContext.getSink(
    path="s3://hem-data-datalake-staging/staging_general/staging_horarioHP/",
    connection_type="s3",
    updateBehavior="LOG",
    partitionKeys=[],
    enableUpdateCatalog=True,
    transformation_ctx="hemhorariosbpi_node3",
)

hemhorariosbpi_node3.setCatalogInfo(
    catalogDatabase="hem-db-staging-tables", catalogTableName="hem-horarios-pbi"
)

hemhorariosbpi_node3.setFormat("glueparquet")
hemhorariosbpi_node3.writeFrame(S3bucket_node1)
job.commit()

Comment: That's the part of the script where it saves it into a table

Comment: Did you end up figuring out why etl wasn't creating the table?

Comment: I did not. I think it had something to do with the bucket I was saving it to, so I just switched buckets and it created the tables just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the updateBehaviour property from `LOG` to `UPDATE_IN_DATABASE`.

Comment: I tried it, but it still didn't create the table. It keeps running without showing any error but the table isn't created.

Comment: Can you please thoroughly check the Glue logs?

Comment: So, I looked through the logs folder and found no error. When I looked through the output folder (which I think is the one that handles the tables, right?) two warnings popped up which were that the WARN JNDI lookup class isn't available and that there isn't a log4h-web module available. In the error folder I found one regarding an uncaught error in thread shutdown-hook-0.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to simulate the situation by creating a glue job using the sample code above and successfully executed the job. Data was written to S3 but Glue table were not created. CloudWatch logs also didn't had any message about why the table was not created. Gave LakeFormation permission on the database to the glue IAM role and then re-run the glue job. Glue table was created.

Lakeformation permission on the database to create/alter/describe was missing.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if you have already figured out the reason or not. I encountered the same issue and after checking the Cloudwatch logs, and it turns out that it has something to do with Lake Formation.

You need to grant the IAM role you pass to the glue job the necessary permission in Lake Formation if you are using it for access control.

You can take a look at [this post](https://repost.aws/questions/QU9B4Xxw-IQKOvm5yYRppd8w/aws-lake-formation-accessdeniedexception-when-calling-the-gettable-operation-insufficient-lake-formation-permission-s-on-table).